# Xamarin Forms add a Tag to a View

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with my Image buttons i want that my function Categorie_Onclick can see with button is clicked. I tried this with adding Tags but it doesnt work. Is there a way to do this?

XAML:

```xml
<!-- Button1 -->
<Image
  x:Name="CityGuideButton1"
  Source="shopping_gray.png"
  Aspect="Fill"
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  VerticalOptions ="FillAndExpand"
  Tag="01">
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
      Tapped="Categorie_Onclick"
      NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

<!-- Button2 -->
<Image
  x:Name="CityGuideButton2"
  Source="secrets.png"
  Aspect="Fill"
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  VerticalOptions ="FillAndExpand"
  Tag="02">
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
  <TapGestureRecognizer
    Tapped="Categorie_Onclick"
    NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

Button handler:

```cs
private async void Categorie_Onclick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Image cmd = sender as Image;
    string txt = TapGestureRecognizer.tag.ToString();
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new CategoriePage());
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could abuse of `StyleId`, `ClassId` or `AutomationId` for this, but it's bad, so don't.

The cleanest way to do this is to define an attached BindableProperty. You can define it in the class you want.

```cs
public class Foo {
    public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Tag", typeof(string), typeof(Foo), null);

    public static string GetTag(BindableObject bindable)
    {
        return (string)bindable.GetValue(TagProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTag(BindableObject bindable, string value)
    {
        bindable.SetValue(TagProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then you can set this Tag in Xaml

```xml
<Image ... local:Foo.Tag="button1" />
```

and get that Tag back from your event handler

```cs
async void Categorie_Onclick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Image cmd = sender as Image;
    string txt = Foo.GetTag(cmd);
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new CategoriePage());
}
```

You might wonder why this is not built into the platform. well, it's likely because with a proper Mvvm usage, this would not be required.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer but i have one little question is it beter to use Mvvm? I am new to Xamarin and have never used Mvvm before.

Comment: it's often better to use Mvvm. But there are always cases when this kind of stuff might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your "tag" property belongs to Image, not TapGestureRecognizer. Unfortunately there is no "tag" property in Xamarin.Forms but you can use StyleId which is mostly used for UITesting. So:

One of your Image properties in XAML:

```
StyleId="02"
```

And inside Categorie_Onclick method you can access it like this:

```
cmd.StyleId; //following your naming
```

But as the best solution I would recommend switching to [MVVM and Commands](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/).

Comment: For this small project i don't need to use MVVM

Comment: Believe at one point you realise damn i should used mvvm. I suggest to create your own mvvm with custom ContentPage and model binding on OnAppearing ContentPage method. Super simple but then you could extend to whatever need and reuse everywhere